# .net core : LinkedIn authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using LinkedIn authentication for my .Net core app.

I have configured the linkedIn options, however the `await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns null ?

```
.AddOAuth("LinkedIn", l_options =>
{
    l_options.ClientId = linkedinSettingsSection.Get<LinkedInAuthSettings>().ClientId;
    l_options.ClientSecret = linkedinSettingsSection.Get<LinkedInAuthSettings>().ClientSecret;

    l_options.CallbackPath = "/PerfromExternalLogin";
    l_options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
    l_options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
    l_options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)";

    l_options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = loginFailureHandler =>
        {
            var authProperties = l_options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(loginFailureHandler.Request.Query["state"]);
            loginFailureHandler.Response.Redirect("/PerfromExternalLogin");
            loginFailureHandler.HandleResponse();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: it's probably because the async method needs you to pass something like `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(settings)`. Haven't seen the linkedin API but I'm guessing

Comment: the GetExternalLoginInfoAsync does not need parameters. I have used it with google and facebook and it works perfectly

Comment: Your code doesn't have the `OnCreatingTicket` handler that actually performs the authentication and parses the response. [Check this tutorial](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/).

Comment: You should check [this LinkedIn extension too](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn), either to use directly or copy. Its main advantage is that it puts all the necessary events in [its own handler](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationHandler.cs)

Comment: This allows it to register itself with a simple ` which allows it to register [with a simple](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationExtensions.cs#L73) `.AddOAuth<LinkedInAuthenticationOptions, LinkedInAuthenticationHandler>`

Answer (score 0):

That seems you are using ASP.NET Identity with LinkedIn authentication . I would suggest you can follow below steps to achieve that :

1. Create `Individual User Account` authentication template Asp.net Core application .
2. Install Nuget package `AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn` to implement LinkedIn authentication in Web app .
3. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select `Manage User Secrets` from the context menu , A `secrets.json` file will open, put your credential in it :

   ```
   {
       "Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientId": "YourClientID",
       "Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientSecret": "YourSecret"
   }
   ```
4. In `Startup.cs` file and modify `ConfigureServices` method:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
       .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

   services.AddAuthentication().AddLinkedIn(options =>
   {
       options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientId"];
       options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientSecret"];
   });

   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```

Comment: I tried to work with the nuget package AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn, but the authentication result returns HttpRequestException: An error occurred while retrieving the user profile.
AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler.CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties, OAuthTokenResponse tokens)

Comment: yes, i have followed all the credential steps but it occurred a problem to retrieve the user profile